# MaxLocksPerFile error in Access for Excel import

Tags: excel, ms-access

Would very much welcome some help on this issue.

I'm trying to import data from an Excel into Access but have been running into the

`File sharing lock count exceeded. Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry`.

So I went into the registry and after multiple increases of the value (from 251c up to 41ffffff) and applying this to all variations of the file within the registry (I found 4 relevant ones), it still didn't work.

So i guess my question would be to clarify what exactly is being locked in?

Because the excel sheet I'm importing has 2500 rows and 50columns so i don't understand where the huge number of locks would be needed for?

I'm using `Access 2010`.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;286153 You may also need to do a compact and repair on your Database and in extreme cases, export everything into a new `.mdb`

Comment: yep, that was the first link I found, but unfortunately it didn't help. The problem is i can't compress the DB since there isn't one yet, as this is the initial import from excel. I'm not sure how to i would apply the 'compact and repair' to an excel sheet.